# Discovery of MongoDB Server IP from NodeJS Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, cloud, service-discovery

I have one instance of MongoDB running on a cloud compute on DigitalOcean.  I have another instance of my Node(Express) app running on another cloud compute.  Is there a way that I can discover the IP of the database such that I don't have to hard code it into my app and therefore can scale easier?  I know you can hook the instances up to a load balancer and hardcode that in, but that isn't ideal and won't work in all circumstances, as it has to be reconfigured every time the environment changes.  I would prefer not to have to make something that accesses the DigitalOcean API, as that is platform-specific, although I am considering it.  The reason that I am asking is that I want to automate configuration as much as possible so that I don't have to a bunch of configuring every time I create/destroy instances.  I am using static IPs, so changing IPs won't be a problem.  I'm looking into service discovery systems such as [consul](https://consul.io), and I might move to something like that but I think it(consul) seems overkill for my app, although I am considering it.

Comment: Be a little bit more clear about this.

Comment: How could I be more concise?  I want to find the IP of a MongoDB Server from a NodeJS server so that I can establish a connection to it.  I thought that would be understandable.

Comment: Have you tried another thing than hooking the instances up to a load balancer and hardcode it in?

Comment: No, I have not tried anything else

Comment: If you try something else and it still doesn't work, come back here and add a little bit more detail.

Comment: I don't have a solution, so what else would I try?  I do not know of a solution to this problem.  That is my question.

Comment: Alright. I'll leave you alone.

Comment: Can you please explain your use case more, like why would the Mongo DB IP change? What will you do when IP changes while your NodeJS server is running and a connection is already established with the old IP? Also how important is this for you? I mean are you ok to put on effort for setting up a service discovery like consul or something similar for just one mongo db ip? Why not just use a DNS entry or something like https://dyn.com/dns/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal means for discovering the current IP(s) of a web resource is using a DNS hostname. This doesn't require any additional services to be installed and will work with public or private IPs as long as the hostname is resolvable. There are low cost domain names available (few US$/year) which also include a service to alias domain hostnames (eg `db.yourdomain.xyz`) to your Digital Ocean hostname or IPs. Recommending a provider is outside the scope of Stack Overflow, but there are many. One aspect to compare is the renewal price, which is often much higher than the initial registration.

If you eventually upgrade your MongoDB deployment from a standalone to a replica set, MongoDB 3.6+ supports a [DNS-based discovery format  (SRV lookups)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#dns-seedlist-connection-format) which allows you to change the hosts in a replica set without reconfiguring clients.

Load balancers and service discovery systems are overkill for managing a single server, but ultimately they expose resources via DNS as well. For example, see [Consul's DNS interface](https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/dns.html) (which also includes [SRV lookups](https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/dns.html#service-lookups) similar to MongoDB's DNS-based discovery format). You could also perform service discovery via HTTP requests to the Consul API, but that is a more complicated integration path.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Environment Variables to avoid hardcoding values into your code. These values can be loaded from the processes environment when the application starts with a package like [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv).

Comment: Welcome dcstone09 to StackOverflow. @Ben I would recommend this solution assuming you have a fixed IP or DNS address for your MongoDB instance. Otherwise, I would look into the first answer, but I wouldn't add the complexity of service discovery unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: I am currently in the development stage of my project and I am looking into scaling my app across many machines, so having to hardcore values, even in env variables isn’t ideal